# To create SlidingupPanel like googleMaps for both android and IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Do you know how to create a SlideUpPanel like GoogleMaps for both Android and iOS using Xamarin?
If I use SliddingupPanel layout is only for android
Help me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use [DKSlideUpPanel](https://github.com/dw2kim/slidingpanel)

It's easy to use and fast

**Steps:**

- First, simply reference the NuGet package in your Xamrin.Forms projects.
- Second, initialize SlidingUpPanel instance either in XAML or C#.
- Lastly, apply the SlidingPanelConfig for your customizations.

**How to use:**

- Add a mainView something like this;

  ```
  <DK:SlidingUpPanel x:Name="spTest">
  <DK:SlidingUpPanel.MainView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
     **MainDesign**
    </StackLayout>
  </DK:SlidingUpPanel.MainView>
  ```
- Set panel ratio and if you want the toolbar visible:

  ```
  <DK:SlidingUpPanel.PanelRatio>0.4</DK:SlidingUpPanel.PanelRatio>
  <DK:SlidingUpPanel.HideNavBar>True</DK:SlidingUpPanel.HideNavBar>
  ```

Check the following guide for an even better understanding of how it works:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-slideuppanel-app/

Comment: Good Solution.Thanks you Hakim

Comment: No problem feel free to revert in case of queries